# Pivoting while grouping in postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum, pivot, postgres-crosstab

I've been using crosstab in postgres to pivot a table, but am now needing to add in a grouping and I'm not sure if that's possible.

I'm starting with results like this:

```
Date          Account#    Type   Count  
-----------------------------------------
2020/1/1         100      Red       5   
2020/1/1         100      Blue      3   
2020/1/1         100      Yellow    7
2020/1/2         100      Red       2 
2020/1/2         100      Yellow    9  
2020/1/1         101      Red       4   
2020/1/1         101      Blue      7   
2020/1/1         101      Yellow    3
2020/1/2         101      Red       8
2020/1/2         101      Blue      6 
2020/1/2         101      Yellow    4
```

And I'd like to pivot it like this, where there's a row for each combination of date and account #:

```
Date          Account#    Red   Blue  Yellow  
---------------------------------------------
2020/1/1         100      5       3     7   
2020/1/2         100      2       0     9   
2020/1/1         101      4       7     3
2020/1/2         101      8       6     4
```

This is the code I've written returns the error "The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values" which makes sense per my understanding of crosstab.

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab(
SELECT date, account_number, type, count
FROM table
ORDER BY 2,1,3'
) AS ct (date timestamp, account_number varchar, Red bigint, Blue bigint, Yellow bigint);
```

(I wrote the dates in a simplified format in the example tables but they are timestamps)

Is there a different way I can manipulate the first table to look like the second? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    account#,
    sum(cnt) filter(where type = 'Red'   ) red,
    sum(cnt) filter(where type = 'Blue'  ) blue,
    sum(cnt) filter(where type = 'Yellow') yellow
from mytable
group by date, account#
```